# How to Disable Verification using Laravel Socialite

Tags: laravel

I am using two registration on my Laravel Application, the default Laravel registration and Laravel Socialite. Both are working fine. When the user registers with default Laravel registration, it sends verification email, but it also sends a verification email with Laravel Socialite, I want to disable sending verification email using socialite but I don't know how to go about this.

Here is the code in my `Login Controller` that handles `Socialite`

```
public function redirectToGoogle()
        {
            return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
        }

        public function handleGoogleCallback()
        {
            try {

                $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

                $finduser = User::where('google_id', $user->id)->first();

                if($finduser){

                    Auth::login($finduser);

                    return redirect('/home');

                }else{
                    $newUser = User::create([
                        'name' => $user->name,
                        'email' => $user->email,
                        'google_id'=> $user->id
                    ]);

                    Auth::login($newUser);

                    return redirect()->back();
                }

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return redirect('auth/google');
            }
}
```

Comment: I added `'email_verified_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` to pick the time, but it's not working

Comment: You need to set 'email_verified_at' to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in database table instead of pass it from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
$user=User::create([
                'name'=>$googleUser->name,
                'email'=>$googleUser->email,
                'google_id'=>$googleUser->id,
                'password'=>md5(rand(1,10000)),
            ]);
            $user->markEmailAsVerified();
```

Comment: More about the solution provided can be found in Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/verification#the-email-verification-handler)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `now()` helper function, for example:

```
$newUser = User::create([
    'name' => $user->name,
    'email' => $user->email,
    'google_id'=> $user->id,
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
]);
```